# Prove that $ \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{7} + ... + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n^2+n+1} = \tan^{-1}\frac{n}{n+2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that 
$$ \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{7} + ... + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{n^2+n+1} =  \tan^{-1}\frac{n}{n+2}$$

I have been trying to solve it step by like $ \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{3} + \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{7}=\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$ and so on but cannot observe any pattern. Could someone suggest something?

Comment: Hint: Observe last term of L.H.S. carefully and note that $\tan^{-1}a-\tan^{-1} b=\tan^{-1}\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$

Comment: Try mathematical induction  !

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305576/is-there-a-way-to-write-this-expression-differently-arctan-1-1nn2  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346929/solving-an-infinite-series-containing-arctan and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552649/sum-n-150-arctan-left-frac2nn4-n21-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Observe last term of $L.H.S.$ carefully and note that $\tan^{-1}a-\tan^{-1} b=\tan^{-1}\frac{a-b}{1+ab}$

Answer (score 8):

HINT: $$\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{r^2+r+1}$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^n \tan^{-1}\frac{(r+1)-r}{1+r(r+1)}$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^n [\tan^{-1} (r+1) -\tan^{-1} r]$$

Comment: Well done!  +1...

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$\arctan\frac {1}{1+k+k^2}=\arctan\frac{(k+1)-k}{1+(k+1)k}=\arctan(k+1)-\arctan k$$

Comment: Well done! +1...